# VBA generating lines inside HTMLBody of an Email depending on the number of rows with value

Tags: vba, excel

So I get a request to order statements and I have a macro that automatically orders them but now I want the same macro to send the email out at the end.  I am at the 70% solution but I am stuck at one critical part.  I don't get a set number or statements to order daily some days its 2 some its 20.

Question: How do I generate a line of text in the body of an email, dependent on the number of rows that have a value.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Email()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Email As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    K = 2
    Do While ws.Cells(K, 1) <> "" ' While column A has cells with data do
' this matches 'Name Of' & cell value and puts it in column E (E1=Name of Joe)
      ws.Cells(K, 5) = "Name Of " & ws.Cells(K, 1).Value  

        K = K + 1
    Loop

    Email = "Hello, <br><br>" & _
            "The following Statements were ordered today: <br><br>" & _
     '===================================================================
                 "<br>" & ws.Cells(k, 5).Value & _
      ' I am trying to get this line to be generated depending on how many 
      ' rows have data in column A so if there are 5 names there are 5 lines
      '==================================================================
                       "<br><br> Thank you." & _
                       "<br><br><br> <i> Call if you have any questions </i>"

    With OutMail
        .to = "me@me.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Statements Ordered"
        .HTMLBody = Email

        .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

So I am looking to replace the line of `"<br>" & ws.Cells(k, 5).Value & _` because that just generates the last row with data because of the last value of K.

I tried to insert the `do while ws.cells(k, 1) <> ""` but no Joy with that to work.  I looked into creating my own function but that was way over my head.

Clarification:

The current email looks like this

```
Hello,

The following Statements were ordered today:

Name of Joe
Name of Bob
Name of Billy

Thank you.

Call if you have any questions.
```

What I am trying to do is have VBA look at Column A and see how many rows there are with data and that generates the line `Name of & the value of the cell`

I also added comments to the code.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what your asking for, is the value of k-2 the number you want printed?

Comment: I updated and added comments hope this helps pls ask questions I am all about trying to figure this out together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will loop through everything in column 5, and put all data into the variable 'myvalue'.

This should be enough to get you started.

```
btm = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
for i = 1 to btm
    myvalue = myvalue & "<br>" & ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
next i

Email = "Hello, <br><br>" & _
                "The following Statements were ordered today: <br><br>" & _
                        "<br>" & myvalue & _
                   "<br><br> Thank you." & _
                   "<br><br><br> <i> Call if you have any questions </i>"
```